# What is the place for asking hardware questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a problem on my phone after buying this [audio cable splitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005MIG5UO), but it's not specific to Android only, so what is the correct place for a question about it?

Specifically, my problem is on my Samsung phone, the jack is now only in mono with sizzle sounds.

Comment: That sounds like an issue that would require contacting support for the product in question.

Comment: It's seems he is just a dealer of a basic china product. My problem is on my samsung phone, the jack is now only in mono with sizzle sounds...

Comment: So how do you expect anyone else to help you resolve the problem that you bought a defective product from a location with no support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decide the best place for a question, we first need to decide what the question is. Allow me to suggest:

1. You mention it's to do with a problem after buying a product. However, in a comment you then imply technical support from the dealer is ruled out. So the question's not about buying or warranty support.
2. You mention Android, but in a comment you home in on the actual problem: "the jack is now only in mono with sizzle sounds". So it's not an Android problem.
3. No, it's an electrical connection problem on a smartphone. And you want to try and fix it yourself.

You will find the folks at [Super User](http://superuser.com) are no strangers to phones and electrical connection problems. They will suggest what to wiggle, spray, dismantle or resolder.

Comment: However, on [su], questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic (except when they interface with a computer). See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). We would immediately flag such a question as off topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill I wonder when that guidance was last reviewed. Super User is for computer enthusiasts, no? [In Less Than Two Years, a Smartphone Could Be Your Only Computer](http://www.wired.com/2015/02/smartphone-only-computer/)

Comment: Smartphones already have their own sites http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/ , http://android.stackexchange.com/, and http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Is a modern phone not a computer?](http://meta.superuser.com/a/2878)

Comment: There will always be overlap between Stack Exchange sites, and if you read the question, it's not even limited to smartphones, so a smartphone site would be too specific anyway. At Super User we're likely to be looking at all kinds of kit, and I stand by my answer that Super User is the best site to get good exposure for this question--and that it's high time we revised that too-exclusive guideline. If you have a different answer to mine, please post it.